# Trying to make input box appear from button click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, addeventlistener

I'm still very new to html css and JS.  I am trying to make an input field appear/toggle from a button click. here is my code so far.

HTML

```
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Competency 15 Event Listeners</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li><button type="text" id="theButton" onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="popup" id="popup"></li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

CSS

```
form{
    width: 50%;

}
 #popup {
    display: none;
 }
```

JavaScript

```
function clickMe(){
    var text = document.getElementById("popup");
  if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
    }
```

I've looked all around the internet and can't seem to find the answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Competency 15 Event Listeners</legend>
            <ol>
                <li><input type="button" value="click here" onclick="clickMe()"></li>
                <li><input type="text" id="show"></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script>
        function clickMe() {
            var text = document.getElementById("show");
            if (!text.style.display) {
                text.style.display = "none";
            }
            if (text.style.display === "none") {
                text.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                text.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>



form{
    width: 50%;

}

#show {
   display: none;
}
```

If you use fieldsets, you should use input with a type button to make buttons. I have changed your button to an input with a type button and now it works.

Also, added another if loop that checks if there is a display property and if it is empty "", it sets it to "none". Without the first if loop it will take 2 clicks to show the input, because first you will need your else to set display to "none" and only the second click will set it to "block".

I dont remember why does it work like that, but its just how CSS functions, if you feel like it, use console.log(text.style) to get a full CSS Object and examine it.

Comment: Thank you! I played around with removing the first 'if loop' and the double click is only needed pressing the button the first time, after that it takes one click back and forth.  Very interesting and something that will stick with me.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things :

1. If the value of button attribute `type` is invalid  (like `text` here), then the value becomes `submit`. Inside a form, clicking `submit` button [refreshes the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). So you will have to use a different type.
2. Initially, the `style.display` is `""` because you are using DOM elements to find it. DOM parser does not have [knowledge about styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#getting_style_information) added with CSS stylesheet. So you will have to include one more condition in your comparison -

```
if (text.style.display === "none" || text.style.display === "") {
```

Alternatively, you could have put the style as inline, which will be parsed by the DOM as below:

```js
function clickMe(){
    var text = document.getElementById("popup");
    console.log(text.style.display);
  if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
form{
    width: 50%;

}
```

```html
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Competency 15 Event Listeners</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="popup" id="popup" style="display: none;"/></li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend toggling CSS classes instead:

```js
function clickMe() {
  var text = document.getElementById("popup");
  text.classList.toggle("hide");
  text.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="theButton" onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button>
<input type="text" name="popup" id="popup" class="hide">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you define the initial element `display` property viaCSS, you may need to use the `getComputedStyle` method to get the current style

```html
<style>
 #popup {
    display: none;
 }
</style>

<form>
  <ol>
      <li><button type="button" onclick=toggleMe()>Toggle me!</button></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="popup"></li>
  </ol>
</form>

<script>
  function toggleMe() {
    var text = document.getElementById('popup')
    text.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(text, null).display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
  }
</script>
```